# UILongPressGestureRecognizer in subview didnot work

Tags: ios, objective-c, long-press

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect imageRect = (CGRect){105, 180, 110, 110};
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"sasuke.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    [imageView setImage: image];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGnizer=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longGo:)];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:longGnizer];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)longGo:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)aGer{
    if(aGer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
    }
}
```

here's the code ,but the func longGo were never work,why?when I use[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longGnizer],it did works.

Comment: Set the UIImageView's userInteraction to `YES`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIImageView`s have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` by default. You have to set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.

Comment: now I added,seems not work

Comment: yeah, u r right,now just antoher control over it so i cant touch it,i changed it's pos, does work.thk u

Comment: Exactly right answer